# Angular: Is using ng-if for managing text strings an anti-pattern?

Tags: angularjs, templating, angular-template

I have an Angular template that renders a different blurb based off of a boolean scope variable:

```
<p ng-if="::verify">Blah blah verification</p>
<p ng-if="::!verify">Blah blah contact us</p>
```

I'm relatively new to Angular and am still trying to figure out the cleanest ways to maintain templates. Is this approach an anti-pattern? Are there other approaches to this?

Comment: The only other option is ng-show/ng-hide. As far as I know the only difference here is that ng-if removes the element from the DOM

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to angular too so I can't speak to whether or not it's an anti-pattern. From the resources I've used thus far it appears show and hide are preferred to using ifs for cleanliness.

I think that stands out for your particular case where you actually have two tags and expressions that will be evaluated while evaluating one gives the result for both. So...

> Are there other approaches to this?

Yes, in this case I would add a function that would return the end of the string that differs and opt for one tag. For example:

`<p>Blah blah {{ctrl.isValid()}}</p>`

With the angular controller code:

```
...
self.valid = false;
self.isValid = function() {
    return self.valid ? "verification" : "contact us";
};
...
```

Seems that's cleaner than any of if, show, or hide (IMHO).